# I want to host my laravel 8 project and when i deploy my project it give me the error

Tags: laravel

I want to host my laravel project, when I upload my project and set env file the server generate the flowing error

```
SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO) (SQL: select * from `sessions` where `id` = LCmr4IjsknuhttKgnCkfMf4PkpkdRcahuZWdmR8h limit 1)
```

my env file is :

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=welsnangarhar_db
DB_USERNAME=welsnangarhar_admin
DB_PASSWORD={)]*]t^A.!Ai
```

Comment: Your database root password is not correct.

Comment: The error is saying you’re connecting to your database using the ‘root’ user but your ‘.env’ file is using a different user. Are you certain the ‘.env’ file on your production server is correct?

Comment: how to change root user

Comment: first of all dont use this db, usernam and password after your problem solved. becouse you published it :-/. your problem is too weired that i can tell its not coding problem, maybe you forget to set [dot] before env file name?? or server problem ??

Comment: Don't use root as a user. Looks like your password is incorrect try changing your password and try again with a new password.

Comment: I have created a new user  and user password which is written in env file

Answer (score 0):

This error states that the username/password both you're using to connect to the database is incorrect. check your **.env file** and see if the database credentials match a database user that has access.

Or you can create a new user in the database and try to use new user credentials.